# MSCRM Retrieve Multiple PlugIn limits the other Retrievemultiple uery

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-365

In my scenario, there is a plugin (Retrieve Multiple) on Annotation. This plugin is nothing just a part of BLOB Storage solution(used for Attachment Management solution provided by Microsoft). So, it is clear that in our CRM, **MicrosoftlLabsAzureBlobstorage** is being used.

Now, I am executing a console app which retrieves multiple annotations through Query Expression. When it tries to fetch records around 500 or 600, it throws below error.

> {The plug-in execution failed because no Sandbox Hosts are currently
>   available. Please check that you have a Sandbox server configured and
>   that it is running.\r\nSystem.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for
>   administrators or support: #AFF51A0F"}

When I fetch specific records or very less records, it executes fine.

So, I my question is that is there any limitation in number for Rerieve Multiple Query ? if retrievemultiple PlugIn exists ?

Is there any other clue that I am not able to find ?

Comment: Is this an on-line implementation or on-premise?

Comment: It is online v8.2.2.2160

Comment: You can show some of your console application code, but I think you have to raise a ticket with MS

Comment: Already following up with MS, they also told the same reason that I have pointed out. There is a plugin on Retrieve Multiple and that is causing an issue when my code is retrieving multiple annotations with documentbody which results in large size.

Comment: Yes, but you're saying the plugin is part of a solution from Microsoft. it's not a support ticket for CRM, but for that particular package

Comment: solution from Microsoft=> Azure Blob Storage. Now, 
my own c# query (Console Application) getting an error when doing 
retrievemultiple and this is happening because solution's plugin is registered on Retrievemultiple.
MS has reverted back that my c# query is trying to fetch much large annotations with retrievemultiple that why error is occuring.
When I run same query on Retrieve instead of retrievemultiple, it is working.

Answer (score 1):

To work around this conflict, in your console application code you may want to try retrieving smaller pages of annotations, say 50 at a time, and loop through the pages to process them all.

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt269606.aspx) provides sample code for paging a QueryExpression.

Here's the abridged version of that sample:

```
// The number of records per page to retrieve.
int queryCount = 3;
// Initialize the page number.
int pageNumber = 1;
// Initialize the number of records.
int recordCount = 0;

// Create the query expression
QueryExpression pagequery = new QueryExpression();
pagequery.EntityName = "account";
pagequery.ColumnSet.AddColumns("name", "emailaddress1");                   

// Assign the pageinfo properties to the query expression.
pagequery.PageInfo = new PagingInfo();
pagequery.PageInfo.Count = queryCount;
pagequery.PageInfo.PageNumber = pageNumber;

// The current paging cookie. When retrieving the first page, 
// pagingCookie should be null.
pagequery.PageInfo.PagingCookie = null;

while (true)
{
    // Retrieve the page.
    EntityCollection results = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(pagequery);
    if (results.Entities != null)
    {
        // Retrieve all records from the result set.
        foreach (Account acct in results.Entities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}.\t{1}\t{2}", ++recordCount, acct.Name,
                               acct.EMailAddress1);
        }
    }

    // Check for more records, if it returns true.
    if (results.MoreRecords)
    {
        // Increment the page number to retrieve the next page.
        pagequery.PageInfo.PageNumber++;

        // Set the paging cookie to the paging cookie returned from current results.
        pagequery.PageInfo.PagingCookie = results.PagingCookie;
    }
    else
    {
        // If no more records are in the result nodes, exit the loop.
        break;
    }
}
```

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327917.aspx) has more info and another sample.

Comment: We had a call with BLOB team and they also say the same that you need to execute in small chunks rather than in large size at a time. Interesting is that when I disabled their plugin (belong to BLOB), my console app is executing fine. This is as per framework of 2 minute time, so no other option except small chunks. Thanks